# How to switch gdb CPU register context from X86 to X64-32 when debugging step by step

Tags: gdb, cpu-registers

```
As we know, during gdb debugging, command 'info reg' can be used to show register 
status. But in some cases, if gdb start with x86 binary, which may jumped into a 
memory block which contains X64-32 instructions, how can I get R9-R15 in step by 
step debugging?
```

info register

set architecture i386:X64-32

```
I tried 'set architecture', but it doesn't work. Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, `info registers` uses the architecture of the current frame and ignores the architecture set by `set architecture`. Is this block of x64-32 instructions contained in a separate ELF file compiled as x32 (ELF header would have file class ELFCLASS32 and machine EM_X86_64) or are they just inline asm?

Comment: It's not inline asm, you can consider it as separate file compiled as X32 without any other section of elf file expect .code block.

Answer (score 3):

2 years later, I finally found that should set architecture i386:x64-32 *BEFORE* target program starting to run.